# javascript - How to insert an img several times into a div using a loop

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hello I am trying to insert an img several times into a div, each time my img will have different properties. My Html code will have a div with an example id called ID_DIV. 
I will have a style section into the html code like this img position absolute.

I will preset the variable **NumberOfTimes** according to the number of img I need into the div.

But I can't manage to make the loop work. Every time I refresh my browser my img appears in a different position, but it wont appear a "**NumberOfTImes**" times.
I have edited my code into this. But the loop wont work anyways. Still without knowing what it is.

```
  function generateImg(){
  var numberOfTimes=prompt("how many times?");
  var div_id1=document.getElementById("div_id1");
  do{
    var oImg=document.createElement("img"); // Creates an oimg node
    oImg.setAttribute('src', 's0me_s0urce'); // sets the source for img file
    div_id1.appendChild(oImg); // append the img to #id Div.         
    document.querySelector('img').style.top = Math.floor(Math.random()*401)+'px';
    document.querySelector('img').style.left = Math.floor(Math.random()*401)+'px';
    numberOfTimes--;
 }while(numberOfTimes>0);
}
```

Please Help. I can't find where is the mistake in this logic.

Comment: is there any error message in console?? your code should work fine, just check the source "s0me_s0urce" to "s0me_s0urce.Extension" and check the value of numberOfTimes for each iteration

Comment: It was the document.querySelector('img') it was a wrong logic. Instead I used oImg (the variable) and it worked.

Comment: Be careful, images might overlap. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/36673274/1636522 for a possible solution :-)

Answer (score 0):

you need to declare "i" outside of the loop otherwise it will not decrement  and will only ever be "NumberOfTimes - 1" and therefore your loop will loop repeadeteldy with the image in the same location. This is also assuming that "NumberOfTimes" is in in the same scope to be used in the first place. Note that I have moved the location of "i" and added a decrement to it in the loop.

```
function RandomPositionImgs(){
var i=NumberOfTimes;
  do{
    var oImg=document.createElement("img"); // Creates an oimg node
    oImg.setAttribute('src', 'some_source'); // sets the source for img file
    document.getElementById("ID_DIV").appendChild(oImg); // append the img to leftSide Div.
    document.querySelector('img').style.top = Math.floor(Math.random()*401)+'px'; // random positioning 
    document.querySelector('img').style.left = Math.floor(Math.random()*401)+'px'; // random positioning
    i--;
 }while(i>0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer is obsolete now. Anyway, here is a way to deal with overlapping images:

```js
var img, i, x, y;
var size = 48, w = 5, h = 3;
var grid = new Array(w * h).map(x => false);
var n = 5; // n > grid.length => infinite loop
var src = 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/6gwfY.gif?s=48&g=1';
var ct = document.getElementById('ct');

ct.style.width = size * w + 'px';
ct.style.height = size * h + 'px';

while (n-- > 0) {
  i = next(), x = i % w, y = (i - x) / w;
  img = document.createElement('img');
  img.setAttribute('src', src);
  img.style.left = size * x + 'px';
  img.style.top = size * y + 'px';
  ct.appendChild(img);
}

function next () {
  var l = grid.length;
  var i = Math.floor(Math.random() * l);
  // as long as this position is not free, try the next one
  while (grid[i]) i = (i + 1) % l;
  return grid[i] = true, i;
}
```

```css
img{position:absolute}
#ct{background:#eee}
#ct{position:relative}
```

```html
<div id="ct"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I really appretiate your time to help me visualize my code problem. If you could help me further with this question I would be very glad. Thank you sir. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36683158/javascript-onclick-event-should-trigger-a-function-and-its-not-working

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your answers you made me realize what I was doing wrong. This is the correct code I did after your comments, its working perfect.

```
 function generateImgs(){
  var numberOfTimes=prompt("how many times?");
  for(i=0;i<numberOfFaces;i++){
    var oImg=document.createElement("img"); // Creates an oimg node
    oImg.setAttribute('src', 'valid source'); // sets the source for img file
    document.getElementById("div id").appendChild(oImg); // append the img to  Div.
    oImg.style.top = Math.floor(Math.random()*401)+'px';
    oImg.style.left = Math.floor(Math.random()*401)+'px';
 }
}
```