# Javascript - Onclick event should trigger a function and it's not working

Tags: javascript, css, html

I am finishing an assesstment for a course certificate. In my final task I am asked to create a mini js game that will generate random faces in two mirror sides and one side will have a  missing face.
 An onclick event above the "*missing face*" should trigger my function **nextLevel()** that will erase the two divs (mirror divs) and generate new content.
 
I have develop this script in order to achieve the problem but I have an specific error for the `onclick` event. It says:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null

But running a DOM viewer it says there is 5 childs added on the leftSide Div. Please, help me I cant find the solution to this issue.

```
  var numberOfFaces=5;
  var theLeftSide=document.getElementById("leftSide");
  var theRightSide=document.getElementById("rightSide");
  var theBody =document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];

    function generateFaces(){
      for(i=0;i<numberOfFaces;i++){
        var oImg=document.createElement("img"); // Creates an oimg node
        oImg.setAttribute('src', 'http://home.cse.ust.hk/~rossiter/mooc/matching_game/smile.png'); // sets the source for img file
        theLeftSide.appendChild(oImg); // append the img to leftSide Div.
        oImg.style.top = Math.floor(Math.random()*401)+'px';
        oImg.style.left = Math.floor(Math.random()*401)+'px';
     }
     copyDiv();
    }
    function copyDiv(){
      var cloned = theLeftSide.cloneNode(true);
      cloned.removeChild( cloned.childNodes[ cloned.childNodes.length - 1 ] );
      theRightSide.appendChild(cloned);
    }
    theLeftSide.lastChild.onclick=function nextLevel(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    numberOfFaces += 5;
    deleteAllChilds();
    generateFaces();
  }; 

  /*
    theBody.onclick =function gameOver() {
      alert("Game Over!");
      theBody.onclick = null;
      theLeftSide.lastChild.onclick = null;
    };
    */
    function deleteAllChilds(){
      while(theLeftSide.childNodes.length>0){
        theLeftSide.removeChild(theLeftSide.childNodes[theLeftSide.childNodes.lenth-1]);
      }
      while(theRightSide.childNodes.length>0){
        theRightSide.removeChild(theRightSide.childNodes[theRightSide.childNodes.lenth-1]);
      }
    }
```

Comment: If your code runs before the DOM is built, it won't find any of the elements you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

generally the

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null

is warned when you're trying to apply an events on a DOM Object which is not loaded yet !! to avoid this verify that your script is loaded in the `<head>` element or if it is in the body be sure that it was loaded before HTML content having as id "leftSide" ..

Comment: If I provide the html code with the script embed would it provide better insight for the question?

Answer (score 0):

It was the position of the function nextLevel. Adding it inside the function generateFaces will provide the usability I was looking for. Thank you all.